# how to fix this error string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am getting this error how to fix this error

```
AAPT: error: string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'.
    error: failed writing to 'C:\Users\syed\Desktop\New folder (8)\Urban Floodingv1.2\BangaloreWeatherNew\app\build\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list\mockDebug\R.txt': The data is invalid. (13).
```

Answer (score 0):

**

> Issue with Large String ,

**
if you are trying to console log a large string then you will face this issue . to fix this you can do so :

```
public static void longLog(String str) {
    if (str.length() > 4000) {
        Log.d("", str.substring(0, 4000));
        longLog(str.substring(4000));
    } else
        Log.d("", str);
}
```

Comment: sorry iam new android devloper how to add console log